# Installing packages with nuget on command line on MacOS?

Tags: mysql, macos, f#, mono, nuget

I'm trying F# on OS X and I'm having trouble installing packages. My problem is to use MySQL.
I have downloaded Nuget and I can launch it. However, I didn't find any useful documentation about how to use it on the command line.

I managed to install `MySQL.Data` by doing

```
mono nuget.exe install MySql.Data
```

which downloaded it to my current repository. Is that normal? I was expecting it to be "installed" in a more central directory.

Moreover, when I try to require it, `r "MySql.Data` it doesn't work. It works if I set the include path properly by doing:

```
fsharpi --lib:MySql.Data.6.8.3/lib/net45
```

But that seems super heavy. Is there a way to add all the installed nuget in the path automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common use I see is

```
mono nuget.exe install mysql.data -OutputDirectory packages -ExcludeVersion
```

Which would install in your project's directory (generally you ignore the packages directory in your repository however and just restore it with a script) and you'd then find it at `packages/MySql.Data/lib/net45`

Downloading nuget to your repository is also common.

You can always write your own script to do the the fsharpi hookups you want, nuget has a lot of convention, so it's possible to pick the right dll from `lib/*/` for your purposes

And it's possible to do it with an fsharp script, here's an [fsx script](https://gist.github.com/jbtule/9243729) that can be executed directly, it downloads nuget, installs from nuget, and then executes another script (with `fake` not `fsharpi`, but that's totally possible.

Comment: What do you mean by nuget has a lot of convention. Can I set the MONO_PATH to `lib/*/` or something equivalent (I tried but it doesn't work)

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Yes, but it won't be what you hoped for.

It is possible to get NuGet to put installed library some specific place. On Mac OS, add the following to the end of `~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config`

```
<configuration>
  <config>
      <add key="repositoryPath" value="/path/to/where/you/want/it/to/go" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

However, (a) NuGet still puts DLLs in different directories, so there is still no single place for `fsharpi` to find them. (b) Anyway `fsharpi` doesn't honor `$MONO_PATH`, Mono's canonical way to add to the DLL search path.

The closest I've come to a workable solution for `fsharpi` is:

1. Whenever you nuget a package, *manually* add it to MONO_PATH (say, in `~/.profile`). E.g., supposing you told nuget to put stuff in `/opt/nuget` you would add:

   export MONO_PATH=$MONO_PATH:/opt/nuget/MySql.Data.6.8.3/lib/net45
2. Whenever you run `fsharpi`, explicitly feed it `$MONO_PATH`:

   fsharpi -I:$MONO_PATH

If you feel adventurous you could then patch the `fsharpi` script to automatically include `$MONO_PATH`.

I find that this is not worth the effort. Simply constructing a script that starts `fsharpi` with the options you need for whatever you're currently working on is a much more practical solution.

I'm an F# programmer on a Mac. My life is like an illicit love affair with someone married: I endure all the little slights because my heart leaves me no choice.